# 「探してくる」には「見つける」という意味は含まれますか？

Tags: meaning

今まで、「探す」には「見つけようとする」という意味しかないと思っていました。辞書が挙げる語義にも、現代において一般的な用法（下記1.と2.）では「見つけようとする」以上の意味は含まれていません。

> 1. 必要なものや失ったものを見つけようとする。「安い下宿を―す」
>   2. ものを見つけるためにかき回す。「押し入れを―す」
>   3. 中にある物を表し出す。「このふる里の女の前にてだにつつみ侍るものを，さる所にて才―しいで侍らむよ」〈紫式部日記〉
>   4. 他の動詞の連用形に付いて，度を越して…する，の意を表す。「ふみ付け〱ふみ―されて土まぶれ」〈浄瑠璃心中天網島上〉
>   （「スーパー大辞林」より、例文を一部割愛）

しかし、「探してくる」「探してきた」という表現になると、文脈によっては「探した上で見つけてくる」「探して見つけて帰ってきた」という意味が入っているように思われます。

> 例1: この犬は毎回ボールをちゃんと探してくる。
>   例2: じゃあ僕が探してくるよ。
>   例3: 友達が適当な動画を探してきた。
>   例4: 今日は家具を探してきた。
>   例5: これまで長い年月探してきた。
>   例6: せっかくまぼろしの親子丼を探してきたのだから、食べて帰らないわけにはいかない。
>   （Googleで検索した結果を参考にひねり出した例文です）

これらの例でいうと、例1と例3です。

- 例1と例3は、実際に犬はボールを見つけ、友達は動画を見つけたという意味になるのでしょうか？
- その場合、その意味はどこから生じているのでしょうか？文法用語に詳しくなく、的確な表現ができませんが、「比喩」ではないし、「文脈にもとづいた慣習的意味付け」のようなものでしょうか。

Comment: 回答は英語でも日本語でもokです。 [Encouraging participation from native Japanese speakers: translating posts](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1318/128) を見たので日本語で投稿してみました。

Comment: ふたつの間に深い関連性があることは間違いないと思いますが、問題は、「意味が含まれている」という概念をどう定義付けするかではないでしょうか。少なくとも客観的な定義付けは困難ではないかという気がします。こんなことを週末の夜中に言っていると、モテないのがバレてしまいますが・・

Comment: In Chinese 找=探す, 来=くる, and guess what? 找来=見つけてくる…

Comment: @l'électeur そのあたりの客観的定義付けを意味論・語用論がやってくれているのかしらと期待しています。

Comment: 新明解国語辞典：来る：②（補動・カ変型）(一)その動作を**すませて**戻る。「買ってくる」

Answer (score 6, accepted):

大変興味深い質問ありがとうございます。

> **例1と例3は、実際に犬はボールを見つけ、友達は動画を見つけたという意味になるのでしょうか？**

確かになりますね。

> **その場合、その意味はどこから生じているのでしょうか？**

手元に本などがないので適当な回答になってしまいますが（いつもですが）、今考えてみた限りでは、この現象は「てくる」の意味として記述されるべきではないかと思います。というのも、

> 被害者の経歴と交友関係を**調べて**きました。
> 今の政治について、10人の専門家に意見を**尋ねて**きました。

という場合、「[調べる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/112369/m0u/%E8%AA%BF%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8B/)」「[尋ねる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/136622/m0u/%E5%B0%8B%E3%81%AD%E3%82%8B/)」自体には「答えや情報を知る」という意味はないのに、この場合は結果を得ていると思われるからです。辞書の「[～てくる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/64270/m0u/%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B/)」の部分のそれらしい意味を見ると、

> ㋒ある動作をしてもとに戻る。…しに行って帰る。
>
> ㋓ある動作・状態をそのまま続けながら、こちらへ近づく。また、そのようにしてこちらへ至る。

としか記載がありませんが、おそらく日本語でこのような「ある目的を目指すが、その目的への到達は意味しない」という動詞の例が少ないため、見落としたか省略したものと思われます。

思うに、「行ってくる」という単純な例においても、ただ単に往復するだけの意味には使わず、「行ったことにより何かをして、戻る」という場合に使われるように思いますし、「～てくる」の意味の一端として、「**Vをして、その結果生じた事態を帯びて戻る**」というまとめ方もできるかもしれません。

Comment: たしかに、「聞いてくる」も同様の例ですね。「てくる」の意味の一端である、という説に納得しました。「帯びてくる」に「てくる」がちゃっかりいるのが微笑ましいです :)

Answer (score 5):

私のようなネイティブスピーカーは思ってもみなかった視点で、なるほどなと思いました。

結論から言うと、「探す」に「見つける」という意味が含まれるかどうかはともかく、「探してくる」はたしかに「見つけてくる」「見つけて戻ってくる」という意味になる場合があります。
「文脈にもとづいた慣習的意味付け」というより一種の動詞句ですね。このままひとつの動詞として記憶するのがいいと思います。

entoさんの例で言うと、#1, #3 に加えて #2 も、おそらく「見つけてくる」という意味で使われることが多いでしょう。

これに対して #5 には「見つけてくる」の意味は含まれていません。#5 における「きた」は、「これまで」「長い年月」と呼応して、「動作や状態が継続したまま現在に至った」ことを示すもの（「くる」の助動詞的用法のひとつ）として感じられ、結果的に #1 / #2 / #3 とは違う構文になるのだと思います。

＃4 はあまり見かけない、やや不自然な文であるように思われます。おそらく、「見つけてきた」のかどうかが判別しづらいため、このような言い回しは回避されるのではないでしょうか。

「見つけてきた」ことを表現するのであれば

> 今日は家具を見つけてきた。

見つけたかどうかはともかく、とにかく「行ってきた」ことを示すのであれば

> 今日は家具を探しに行ってきた。（しかし収穫はなかった、残念！）

あたりがごく自然な発話であるように感じられます。

＃6もちょっと意味がとりづらいです。まず「食べて帰る」という以上、この時点ではまだ出先にいるわけですから、そもそも「見つけて帰ってきた」という語義にはそぐわないような。。。

> せっかくまぼろしの親子丼を探してきたのだから、食べないわけにはいかない。

これなら、やはり「見つけてきた」「見つけて、持ち帰った」の意味で、自宅かどこかでこれから食べようとしているのだな、とわかります。
もしくは、#5 と同様の表現だとするなら、

> これまでさんざん苦労してまぼろしの親子丼を探してきたのだから、ここで食べて帰らないわけにはいかない。

こんな感じでしょうか。

以上、参考文献も示さずに個人的印象だけで書いてしまいましたがご容赦を！

Comment: 動詞句になることで意味が変化することがあるということですね。それにしても「探してくる」が「見つけてくる」を直接意味していない感じがしてもやもやしています。何らかの意味の「すりかえ」があるというか、暗示しているだけというか。例えばもし辞書に「探してくる」を載せるとしたら、語義の一つとして「見つけてくる」は入るものでしょうか。

Comment: #6 について、元にした文を掘り返しました: 「親子丼を探してきたのに、鶏南蛮を食べてしまいました」で、お店のレビュー文の一部でした。「...を探してこの店に来たのに」というように、それぞれが独立した動詞として機能しているのかなと思います。（例文一覧に入れるには他と違いすぎたかも）

Comment: そのような「すりかえ」はどの言語にも普通にあるものだと思いますよ。たとえば英語の Why don't you ～ は一見ただ「なんで～しないの？」と理由を問うているだけのように見えるのに、実は提案や勧誘、お願いの意味なのだと昔習いました。なんだか相手を非難しているみたいだなあ、とか、ずいぶん「もやもや」したものです（笑） 「探してくる」を辞書に載せるとしたら、その解説には間違いなく「見つけてくる」は入ります。たぶん語義リストのトップにくるんじゃないかな。#6 についてはおっしゃるとおりですね。その「きた」は「この店まで来た」の意味でしょう。

Answer (score 0):

Allow me beating the dead horse.

I think 探し出す should be used (instead of 探す) in the examples 1 and 3.